# header function filename is not working in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

header function filename is not working in PHP. I try to export a CSV file but it always downloads the page name only like export.php
I try so many codes and force download. but I can't. plz anyone help me

```
enter code here
if(isset($_POST["export"]))
{    include 'database/config.php';
     include "database/database.php";
     $db = new database();
     $fn = "csv_".uniqid().".csv";

     $file = fopen($fn, "w");
     $query = "SELECT * from wp_terms";
     $read = $db -> select($query);
     fputcsv($file, array('ID', 'Name', 'slug', 'term group'));
     if($read) {
        while ($row = $read->fetch_assoc()) {
          fputcsv($file, $row);
        }
      }
     header('Content-Type: text/csv; charset=utf-8');
     header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$fn);

     fclose($file);
   }
```

Comment: Did you check the headers to see if they are correct or if you are maybe missing some quotes in `header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$fn);`?

Comment: Are you use wordpress right ?

Comment: @kerbholz yes there was some quotes problem. i correct them but still its not working

Comment: @Dhruv i just use wordpress database.

Answer (score 0):

This will perfectly  work for me so try following code.

```
add_action("admin_init", "download_csv");

function download_csv() {

  if (isset($_POST['download_csv'])) {

    global $wpdb;

    $sql = "SELECT `sub_email` FROM `wp_terms`";

    $rows = $wpdb->get_results($sql, 'ARRAY_A');

    if ($rows) {

        $csv_fields = array();
        $csv_fields[] = "first_column";
        $csv_fields[] = 'second_column';
        $current_date = date("Y-m-d");

        $output_filename = 'subscriber_list'.$current_date.'.csv';
        $output_handle = @fopen('php://output', 'w');

        header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
        header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
        header('Content-type: text/csv');
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=' . 
        $output_filename);
        header('Expires: 0');
        header('Pragma: public');

        $first = true;
       // Parse results to csv format
        foreach ($rows as $row) {

       // Add table headers
            if ($first) {

               $titles = array();

                foreach ($row as $key => $val) {

                    $titles[] = $key;

                }

                fputcsv($output_handle, $titles);

                $first = false;
            }

            $leadArray = (array) $row; // Cast the Object to an array
            // Add row to file
            fputcsv($output_handle, $leadArray);
        }

        //echo '<a href="'.$output_handle.'">test</a>';

        // Close output file stream
        fclose($output_handle);

        die();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: i use your all header functions but still it downloaded as .php file. if i remove all header function then it aromatically download  as csv in htdocs folder.